# Why do DVDs play on one drive and not on another?

Tags: dvd, ubuntu-18.04

I have an external Buffalo Blu-Ray drive (BRXL-PT6U2VB) and successfully played DVDs on it. Recently I bought a set of 5 movies on DVD and the drive refused to recognize any of them. It would spin up and attempt to read from the disc, but the disc would never show up in the file manager, nor did I get the pop-up window asking me what to do with the newly-inserted DVD. Attemptng to open the disc with VLC also failed.

I then tried a different external drive (a Dell DW316) on the same computer, which reads these DVDs with no issue. I get the usual pop-up, choose VLC and the disc will play.

The Buffalo drive will still read other discs (including movie DVDs), just not the ones from the set. All DVDs involved should be Region 2.

OS is Ubuntu MATE 18.04, with the DVD playback components installed.

- Why do these DVDs work on one drive but not on another? Could this be due to some kind of copy protection (other than DVD-CSS), potentially something that violates DVD standards, causing some drives to reject the disc as being faulty?
- Are there any workarounds for this (apart from using a different drive)?
- If not, what should I look for when shopping for a new drive, in order to get one that will read most DVDs, preferably all?

Comment: They are definitely DVDs (the drive that does read them does not even support Blu-Ray) and all of them were acquired from a reputable retail store. Looking at `~/.dvdcss`, I see the one that works appears to be unencrypted, though.

Comment: A lot of copy protection schemes are known to cause problems with some models of drives and not with others.

Comment: Have you checked that the DVD drive is set for Region 2? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/regionset.8.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I checked on the Buffalo, it has no region code set. (Can’t check the Dell anymore as I’ve returned it already.) I noticed the DVD which worked is a Region 0 DVD, but I have also found some Region 2 DVDs that the Buffalo will read (the ones that don’t work are also Region 2). So the Buffalo doesn’t categorically reject region-coded DVDs if it has no region code set. Back when I bought my first DVD player in 2002/3, I was told that some DVDs will refuse to play in region-free players, though the practice was not very widespread back then—not sure what the situation is now.

Comment: @EugenRieck any idea where I can find more details on that, e.g. which copy protection schemes exist and how drives handle them?